# Backing up Redmine w/SQLITE on 2003 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, redmine

I don't have any attachments or plugins, do I just need to backup the .db and config files?  I'm about to migrate to new hardware and don't want to lose my Redmine stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the config files and database files would be fine, but you could also dump a copy of it out just to be extra safe.

```
sqlite <mydatabase>
.dump >file.sql
```